# Batch PHP image upload slow, architecture change?

Tags: php, jquery, image-processing

I've build a CMS with photo album. Pretty simple, most stuff static, static HTML pages, no database, just (as little as possible) text files containing some JSON stuff.
The webinterface for the admin panel is all in jQuery with a PHP (Zend Framework) based backend. A much as possible is done within the browser so the backend is pretty bare.
Now the photo album works currently like this:

- Clicking link 'Media'
- Fetching a JSON string from the backend containing an object with all albums and for every album all the photo's
- Rendering an unordered list with all the albums
- Rendering an unordered list within each album list item with all the pictures

Uploading:

- Drop one or more jpeg/png files into the browser to create a new album
- Drop one or more jpeg/png files into an album to append those files to the album under the cursor
- Send all dropped files (using [this](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) jQuery drag drop upload plugin) to the backend
- Backend receives all files (while displaying a nice progress bar)
- Backend loops through all uploaded files, while the webinterface displays a nice spinner
- Each file is resized to a maximum size specified and renders a thumbnail at max 133x133 px
- Each file is appended to an array with the serverside filename and thumbnail name
- [Not yet implemented: rendering the (updated) static html page for the album overview and for each image]
- Array with all newly uploaded files is converted to JSON and sent to client
- Webinterface appends all new files as list items (displaying the thumbnail)
- Uploading done

This is all going pretty well, upto +- 600 images or +- 900MB. That's fine by me, if the user wants to upload more files at once, well, do it in two stages. The problem is, the backend processing is a bitch. Converting 100+ images at a good size (1.5MB each) to the maximum size and generating the thumbnail is taking way to long. I'm doing this with PHP GD. Didn't take me too much time (or no time at all), to find out that that's the problem. My guess is that there is no way I'm going to speed this up within PHP.

So here are a few questions:

1. Will ImageMagick be faster? I'm not a fan, so please so no, also, I don't want to install this on my server that badly..
2. Is there a really, really lightweight command-line program that does the same with just a few commands (and I know that I'm not alluding to ImageMagick)?
3. If the answer to the previous question is no: what would be the best way to do this? Don't say Java, I'm no that big of a fan of Java also. Some C(-dialect)? Preferably one with a powerful, yet lightweight image library for the nearest neighbor, bilinear and bicubic interpolation algorithms.
4. Could my architecture be changed? At this moment, the images start appearing in the browser once the thumbnail is inserted, thus after the whole JSON array is received, causing the entire action having to complete and generating all the image data before any kind of feedback is received in the browser. This means that the spinner (without any indication of how long the process is going to take or how many images have been completed) will be displayed for a long, long time. Is it an idea to use Javascripts FileReader to preload the images from the users system, generate the thumbnails in the browser and display them after uploading is done immediately? And on the backend: just receiving the file, writing them to disk, executing a command-line command, immediately send response to browser and converting in the background?
5. How do I prevent client side abort event of an AJAX request? When uploading and converting, a warning should be displayed when the user want to close the page or when the #hash is being tried to change.

Thanks. Hope you guys can help me. Just so you know: the client side is pretty complex with way to much code. I'd rather change the backend.